# What is the difference between AddObject and AddToMyTable (specific table name)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm very newbie in MVC 4 and Entity-Framework

If this question does not make sense, please let me explain better.

During the example I'm working on, I have noticed that I can make an insertion to database either using AddObject or AddToMyTableName.(my specific table name which is exist in database)

So I'm kinda confused what is the difference between these?
And which one I should use in what cases?

Here is very simplified example:

In the controller:

This is example for AddObject:

```
using (myProj.Models.myProjEntities db = new Models.myProjEntities())
  {
      myProj.Models.TestClass myTestClass = new myProj.Models.TestClass();
      myTestClass.prop1 = "test1";
      myTestClass.prop2 = "test2";

      db.MyTable.AddObject(myTestClass);
      db.SaveChanges();
  }
```

And here is the example for AddToSpecificTable:

```
using (myProj.Models.myProjEntities db = new Models.myProjEntities())
  {
      myProj.Models.TestClass myTestClass = new myProj.Models.TestClass();
      myTestClass.prop1 = "test1";
      myTestClass.prop2 = "test2";

      db.AddToMyTable(myTestClass);
      db.SaveChanges();
  }
```

Both of them are inserting the values to db and both are working same in my example. I'm pretty sure there are some cases when one of them is working , the other will not.

Can anyone please explain the difference?

Thanks

Comment: Is this even related to MVC at all? Seems like a question about EntityFramework perhaps?

Comment: I'm sorry, the example that I was working on was MVC 4, you are right. @Queti has already edited before than me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `AddTo<TEntity>` method is now considered deprecated and has been used with `EF4` and previous versions. With `EF4.x` the new `AddObject()` was introduced as replacement method for `AddTo<TEntity>` but for some (unknown) reason the `AddTo<TEntity>` method was still available even though it's was recommended to use the new `AddObject()` method. As of now, with `EF5+` you can just use `Add()`. It's hard to find the exact reasons for the replacement of the methods but I guess this is most probably historical reasons and as the `EF` evolved so the methods were changed to reflect the new versions.

So if you consider why (if in any scenario) the one is better than the other, than just use the most common one (Of course if you don't have some version restrictions like, if you are using EF 4 for example). Otherwise you are not gaining anything and usually after some method is marked as deprecated sooner or later it's removed, so if you use `AddTo<TEntity>` you might need to rewrite parts of your code due to the fact that in some future version this method is no longer presented.